# Reversing a string using stack in x86 NASM

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to write a function in x86 NASM assembly which reverses order of characters in a string passed as argument. I tried implementing it using stack but ended up getting error message 
`*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated` 
`Aborted (core dumped)`
Code below:

```
section .text
global reverse
reverse:
        push ebp                ; epilogue
        mov ebp, esp
        mov eax, [ebp+8]
        xor ecx, ecx            ; ecx = 0
        push ebx                ; saved register
push_eax:
        mov edx, [eax]          ; edx = char at eax
        test edx, edx
        jz inc_eax              ; if edx == 0, move eax pointer back and pop eax
        push edx
        inc eax         
        inc ecx                 ; counter + 1
        jmp push_eax
inc_eax:
        sub eax, ecx            ; move eax back to beginning of string
        mov ebx, ecx            ; to move eax back at the end of function                         
pop_eax:      
        test ecx, ecx           ; loop counter == 0
        jz end  
        pop edx                 
        mov [eax], edx          ; char at eax = edx
        inc eax                 ; eax++
        dec ecx                 ; ecx--
        jmp pop_eax
end:
        sub eax, ebx
        pop ebx                 ; saved register
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
```

C declaration:

```
extern char* reverse(char*);
```

I've read somewhere that you get this error when trying to for instance write something in an array that is longer than allocated but i don't see how would that function do it? 
 
Also when instead of using `ebx` at the end I manually move the pointer in `eax` back (string in C of length 9 -> `sub eax, 9`) I get the reversed string at the output followed by 2nd, 3rd and 4th char. (No matter the length of the string I declare in C). So for instance
`input: "123456789" 
output: "987654321234"` 
but that only happens when I move `eax` manually, using `ebx` like in the code above outputs some trash.

Answer (score 2):

[Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59097136/12381289) is the answer you are looking for.  However, may I comment on the technique?  Must you use the stack?  Do you already know the length of the string, or must you calculate/find that yourself?

For example, if you already know the length of the string, can you place a pointer at the first and another at the end and simply exchange the characters, moving each pointer toward the center until they meet?  This has the advantage of not assuming there is enough room on the stack for the string.  In fact, you don't even touch the stack except for the prologue and epilogue.  (Please note you comment that the epilogue is at the top, when it is an 'ending' term.)

If you do not know the length of the string, to use the above technique, you must find the null char first.  By doing this, you have touched each character in the string already, before you even start.  Advantage, it is now loaded in to the cache.  Disadvantage, you must touch each character again, in essence, reading the string twice.  However, since you are using assembly, a repeated *scasb* instruction is fairly fast and has the added advantage of auto-magically placing a pointer near the end of the string for you.

I am not expecting an answer by asking these questions.  I am simply suggesting a different technique based on certain criteria of the task.  When I read the question, the following instantly came to mind:

```
  p[i] <-> p[n-1]
  i++, n--
  loop until n <= i
```

Please note that you will want to check that 'n' is actually greater than 'i' before you make the first move. i.e.: it isn't a zero length string.

Comment: Yup, looping pointers until they cross in the middle is significantly more efficient than expanding each byte to a dword and pushing / popping from the stack.  Even if you had to `strlen` the string before this, that's still less work than pushing while doing strlen.  There was a Q&A about doing it this way recently (from the same asker) where I explained efficiency in comments: [String reverse function x86 NASM assembly](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/104328549).  Especially if you use `bswap` to byte-reverse dwords or qwords on the fly, or even better SSSE3 `pshufb` to do 16B at a time.

Comment: See also https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92246 for GCC auto-vectorization of a simple array reverse loop for `short[]` with AVX512.  Compile the same code with other target options to get simpler asm.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a string of 1-byte characters, you want `movzx edx, byte [eax]` byte loads and `mov [eax], dl` byte stores.

You're doing 4-byte stores, which potentially steps on bytes past the end of the array.  You also probably overread until you find a whole dword on the stack that's all zero.  `test edx, edx` is fine if you correctly zero-extended a byte into EDX, but loading a whole word probably resulted in overread.

Use a debugger to see what you're doing to memory *around* the input arg.

(i.e. make sure you aren't writing past the end of the array, which is probably what happened here, stepping on the buffer-overflow detection cookie.)